# Add columns of data.table by regex

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to add specific columns of a `data.table` and would like to choose the columns by a regex. Take the following example.

```r
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    x_0 = c(1, NA, 0), x_1 = c(2, 4, NA), x_2 = c(3, 5, NA), x_3 = c(NA, 6, NA), 
    y_0 = c(6, NA, 0), y_1 = c(5, 3, NA), y_2 = c(4, 2, NA), y_3 = c(NA, 1, NA)
)

mydt
   id x_0 x_1 x_2 x_3 y_0 y_1 y_2 y_3
1:  1   1   2   3  NA   6   5   4  NA
2:  2  NA   4   5   6  NA   3   2   1
3:  3   0  NA  NA  NA   0  NA  NA  NA
```

I would like to add the columns which have the tag 0. So instead of columns `x_0` and `y_0` I would like to have a new column which equals to `x_0 + y_0`, so something like this:

```r
my_preferred_dt
   id x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 new_col
1:  1   2   3  NA   5   4  NA       7
2:  2   4   5   6   3   2   1      NA
3:  3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA       0
```

As I have lots of such columns I would like to choose them based on a regex (`"_0$"`).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Reduce` in combination with `SD`/`SDcols` to sum (via `regex`) only the columns you want:

```
mydt[, new_col := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols=grep("_0$", names(mydt), value=T)]
```

if you need to remove the "..._0" variables:

```
mydt[, grep("_0$", names(mydt), value=T) := NULL]

mydt
#   id x_1 x_2 x_3 y_1 y_2 y_3 new_col
#1:  1   2   3  NA   5   4  NA       7
#2:  2   4   5   6   3   2   1      NA
#3:  3  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA       0
```

Comment: You can also try out [`endswith`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/640ec81bbfe183991185), which you would be able to use like: `mydt[, new_col := Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols = endswith("0")][]`. +1

Comment: thanks @AnandaMahto, nice function I didn't know of! :-)